# Trying to use QGIS API to perform a set of tasks

Tags: pyqgis

Below is the code block that I am having issues with:

```
...
# Create a new layer for selected features
export_file = '<filepath>/exported_features.shp'
export_options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
export_options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer
export_options.layerName = 'Exported Features'
export_options.fileEncoding = 'UTF-8'
export_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.create(export_file, export_options.fileEncoding, feature_layer.fields(), feature_layer.wkbType(), feature_layer.crs(), 'ESRI Shapefile', export_options=export_options)
export_writer.addFeatures(feature_layer.getFeatures())
export_writer.commit()
```

When I run this section, VSCode proceeds to throw a TypeError at me (see below):

```
TypeError: QgsVectorFileWriter.create(): argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'
```

According to the [PyQGIS documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Vector/QgsVectorFileWriter.html), the second argument is supposed to be a string.

The other issue I have is that I specified the encoding to be 'UTF-8', yet when I add the shapefile to QGIS manual from my folder directory, the encoding is 'window-1252' (never heard of this)[image]

Comment: Try help(QgsVectorFileWriter.create) from the Python console for the parameters.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#a742822122c57f88441a373f47ffcdf3f), the 2nd argument of the `create()` method is a `QgsFields` object.